# Ruby on rails guides, could not find rails with ajax in the index contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Quick question:

I have been learning ruby on rails and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html is really good and helping a lot in learning rails. While i was searching for rails with AJAX, i found http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html in the search results. 
However i could not find it in the home page or the Guides Index tab on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html. How can I find these hidden links like rails with AJAX?

Comment: If you take a look at the first few sections of that guide, it looks like it's not finished yet. That may be why it's not included in the list of guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the guide is not present in the documents.yml file that defines which guides are displayed. I'm going to post on the docs mailing list as to why this is the case.

UPDATE: as Emily pointed out, that guide is not finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/guides/source

Each of the textile files listed there are converted to html files for the guides. If you replace the .textile extension with .html, you should be able to find the page on the guides site. For instance: _welcome.textile can be found here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/_welcome.html

Comment: That's for the edge rails, the guides are different. If you want those, go to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/